# Trying to compile c++ files of a toolbox but cmake is not able to find all required boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, toolbox

I am trying to install a toolbox named "Mocapy" and compile all its files. Once the I have downloaded the files, it asks me to type to commands in the directory .
..

cmake .
make

But when I type cmake ., the output is

```
...
-- Boost version: 1.52.0
-- Boost version: 1.52.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
--   program_options
--   thread
running /usr/bin/cmake -E create_symlink "/home/vishalnus/Downloads/Mocapy++-1.07/examples/data" "/home/vishalnus/Downloads/Mocapy++-1.07/examples/data"  2>&1
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Boost version: 1.52.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Boost version: 1.52.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
-- Could NOT find Boost
...
```

I am not sure why is it able to find only few Boost libraries and not all, can anyone help me please..

Comment: Depending on your system, the Boost libraries can be installed in discreet packages, not all together. As a result, you may only have a portion of the Boost libraries installed.

Comment: Agrees with ScoPi. What system r u on? on debian, apt-get install libboost-dev gets most of the libs/headers